# Opening a new line in evil-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, evil-mode

Consider the following piece of code:

```
(goto-char (point-max))
(insert "\n")
```

In normal state of evil-mode goto-char moves the cursor to the end of line visually, but it points *before* the last symbol, not after. Although the example above works just fine — it works as if the cursor is pointing *after* the last symbol so the last symbol is not carried to the next line which is a correct behavior. I wonder how evil determines that it needs to insert after the last symbol, not before.

The reason I ask about this is because I am trying to understand why hitting enter in haskell-mode repl in normal state in evil-mode puts the last symbol of the current line on the next line. It looks like `(insert "\n")` is invoked in a callback and evil doesn't know that it needs to maintain the compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what the question is, but I presume you want to avoid moving the last character to the next line upon hitting enter.

To mimic Vim's behavior, the cursor moves back a point after exiting insert state.  As a by-product, `(insert "\n")` at the end of the line occurs just before the character on which the cursor is sitting, which puts it before the newline.

To disable this compatibility feature, do `(setq evil-move-cursor-back nil)` (or use `setq-local` if you only want to disable in the REPL) and you should be able to avoid putting the last symbol on the next line.

Comment: The problem was that haskell-mode was not executing both of those commands in the same function, so evil had a chance to move the cursor one character back. And there is not good way to work around that except for putting both of those in the same method.

Comment: Wrapping it in a `progn` should also work: `(progn (goto-char (point-max)) (insert "\n"))`.